Updating ptp4l configuration parameters while service is running
Scenario:
Im running Linuxptp on Raspbian OS buster kernel 5.10.110 with a Hat capable of hardware timestamping. Ptp is working fine and device is synchronizing to TSN master.
The ptp service that runs on boot is defined in /usr/lib/systemd/system/ptp4l.service as following
[Unit]
Description=ptp4l service
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/ptp4l
ExecStart= /usr/sbin/ptp4l -q -i RT0 -i RT2 -f /usr/share/ptp.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Question
Now I want to update a parameter that is already defined in /usr/share/ptp.conf while the ptp4l service is running. I dont want to restart the service as it takes 4-5 seconds to restart. As per my searches, reloading a service doesnt make the service read the config file (in this case /usr/share/ptp.conf) again which is given in the command itself.
Is it possible to put the parameters that needs to be updated in a separate xyz.conf file, set that file as the EnvironmentFile of the service, and then perhaps keep updating the xyz.conf and using systemctl edit ptp4l to make ptp4l read the EnvironmentFile? Or is there any other possible way to achieve the required results without updating the source code to periodically read the ptp.conf file?
What Ive looked into so far

ExecReload: Although the service doenst have reload capability, from my understanding it wouldve been useless for my use case since reload wont re-read the configuration file i.e. /usr/share/ptp.conf.
Acc. to How to ask systemd service to reload its environment variables on runtime once the service has started, its config parameters cant be changed.
Acc. to Make systemd service understand change in configuration file EnvironmentFile cant be read again by the process via reload, but in my case there is no EnvironmentFile.
How to set environment variable in systemd service? Is this possible, if i put the parameters that I want to update in a separate .conf file and edit the service while it is running?

